# How to tell Git to ignore a bad commit and use most recent one instead?

Tags: git, github, command-line

I committed my changes and tried to push it to Github. It failed because one of my files was too large. I realized that a mistake I had made earlier had generated a very large XML file, so I fixed the problem and tried committing and pushing again. It's still trying to push the bad commit instead of the one I had just made.

How can I tell Git to ignore the bad commit and instead push the most recent one? I have tried looking it up, and I'm seeing people recommending different commands and different methods of doing it. I am new to Git, so I want to be sure of what I'm doing before I screw something up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git tracks your commits and tries to push them at once. i.e. now git is trying to push your bad commit + your good commit.
You need to "undo" the bad local commit, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6376039/1695393) should help you take care of it.

Comment: I tried this as suggested: git reset --soft HEAD~1 and it worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Cool! Git can be a pain at the beginning, but it grows on you! :-)